# Can I counter a creature with Shroud?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing with a counter deck, and my opponent played [Algae Gharial](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Algae%20Gharial), which has shroud. Could I counter it?

Comment: You can't counter a creature at all. I presume you are asking if one can counter a *creature spell* with Shroud?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Shroud on a card only works if the card is on the battlefield. In order to not be able to counter it the spell would have to have "~ cannot be countered [by spells or abilities]".

> **702.18a** Shroud is a static ability. “Shroud” means “This permanent or player can’t be the target of spells or abilities.”
>
> **110.1.** A permanent is a card or token **on the battlefield**. A permanent remains on the battlefield indefinitely. A card or token becomes a permanent as it enters the battlefield and it stops being a permanent as it’s moved to another zone by an effect or rule.

Comment: @user16086 If this answered your question, then you can accept it by clicking on the green check mark next to the answer.